# British lady in a strange land

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Where people are shown in delight (8)
>   5. Stray people of Indo-Aryan heritage putting one foot in front of the other (4)
>   8. Loop back of static web address (4)
>   9. Wings of sparrow grant license to being a bird (7)
>   10. Falsely lead to agreement (4)
>   11. Elderly gang leader is caught by retired prosecutor in possession of ecstasy (4)
>   13. French law regarding wine country (5)
>   14. Like Chicago with extreme preference for one woman (5)
>   15. Los Angeles sportsman (a Charger) maybe facing final in Denver (6)
>   18. Rejections of broken nose (4)
>   21. Posted in absentia (4)
>   24. Silver shown in home as sign of respect (6)
>   28. Gamblers' last voyage to Vegas hot spot (5)
>   29. Triad is controlling secret dance club (5)
>   30. In Rome, before going around a mountain (4)
>   31. It has dried up in parallel (4)
>   33. Photos taken with these before al Ghul entered (7)
>   34. Between friends, Dr. Jones is said to be independent (4)
>   35. Plenty of car parks (4)
>   36. In addition, head of doctors is inside showing places for hospital visitors (8)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Letter made with communication impediment sent back in a long time (7)
>   2. A break? Treat without the first sign of respect, in my experience (3, 4)
>   3. United Nations' second leading lawyer spread falsehoods (6)
>   4. Chicken coming from Colorado hospital room (6)
>   5. Redness associated with the rise of red, primarily self-steering, devices (7)
>   6. Mineral resource is valuable in Sweden (3)
>   7. *1001 Nights* hero and British lady in a strange land (7)
>   12. Some strange, weary grass consumer (3)
>   16. In my humble opinion, revolutionary leader left resistance unit (3)
>   17. A kind of order to throw up as a joke (3)
>   19. Couple of taboos about time in Iran north-faced province (7)
>   20. Special lids she protects (7)
>   22. Promised to endure being confused about ultimate questions (7)
>   23. Protagonists not in favour of losing wrestling competition finals to a religion's followers (7)
>   25. Choose to stir pot (3)
>   26. American with a piercing head ache (6)
>   27. Bruised feet with same upcoming symptoms (6)
>   32. Colony inhabitant is not able to take off top (3)

Comment: Title should be [Gertrude Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gertrude_Bell) :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> This uses the usual notation: `*` is anagram, `<` is reversal, `(ddef)` is double definition, `()` is insertion, `_XYZ_` is hidden word, `X_`/`_X` is first/last letter.
>
>  Additionally, there are a few less standard types of wordplay: a triple definition (in 17-Down, marked by `(3def)`), a letter swap (in 5-Across, "ROMA" swaps the two final letters to become "ROAM"), and a letter change (in 14-Across).
>  
>  [image]
>  [image]